# Extract The Windows 10 Notifications History

Tags: c++, windows

I am looking for a way to extract the data from the windows 10 notifications bar. I am using c++. I just want to print the data on a cmd console.

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/mohabouje/WinToast

Comment: That tool is not useful. I want to find a method to extract the data.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no API to access the data you are asking for

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609521/windows-10-toast-notifications-desktop-application), There is not explicit way to do so, you might want to check WinToast (further explanation can be found in the link).